# Access redux store array value on flatlist react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I want to access image filename inside redux store array to be displayed in FlatList, but I am not sure how to access all the filename array value.

This is my Initial State

```
var InitialState = Record({
    query : null,
    searchResults: new (Record({
        total: null,
        lastPage: null,
        items : [],
        perPage : null,
        currentPage : null,
        nextPageUrl: null,
        prevPageUrl:null,
    }))(),
})
```

The `items` array looks like this

```
[ { id: 1050,
user_id: null,
name: 'Item A',
description: null,
image :
{
   id : 150,
   filename : 'imageA.jpg'
}
},
{ id : 1051,
user_id: null,
name: 'Item A',
description: null,
image :
{
   id : 152,
   filename : 'imageB.jpg'
}
},
......
]
```

This is my Flatlist to display the image

```
<View>
       ...
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.search.searchResults.items}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => this._renderItemInfo(item)}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
        />
      </View>
```

This is the renderItemInfo function

```
_renderItemInfo(item, index){
    return(
      <View style={styles.resultBox}>
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Image
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
          source={{uri: 'https://www.somewebsite.com/image/'+ this.props.search.searchResults.items[0].image.filename}}
        />
        <Text id={item.id} style={{paddingLeft:5}}>{item.id} {item.name}</Text>
      </View>
        <Divider/>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

On the source of image, How do I access all filename?

```
this.props.search.searchResults.items[0].image.filename
```

This only access first array.

If I put index on the array key

```
this.props.search.searchResults.items[index].image.filename
```

It gives this error

> TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.search.searchResults.items[index].image.filename')

Any idea how to access the image filename value for all results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `this.props.search.searchResults.items` as the data property of the flatlist, which means the `_renderItemInfo` function will be passed each member of that array as it's `item` argument.

That means you should just be able to access `item.image.filename` when you set the uri of your image component.